# CollectionView not centered on iOS in MAUI

Tags: ios, maui, collectionview

I want to create a horizontally oriented collection of items centered on the screen. I'm using CollectionView to do so. Using the code below, my CollectionView is centered on Android but is left-justified on iOS. I've tried messing with all the HorizontalOptions for the VerticalStackLayout and CollectionView. I've tried playing around with WidthRequest for both the VerticalStackLayout and CollectionView as well. This definitely  seems like a bug, but I'd love to know if any of you have found a workaround or have ideas for one.

In the code below, CollectionViewElements is a simple 3-element List of strings " 1 ", " 2 ", " 3 ".

```
 <VerticalStackLayout
        Margin="10,30,10,0"
        HorizontalOptions="Center">

        <Label Text="Sample Label - Centered" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>

        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionViewElements}" HorizontalOptions="Center" SelectionMode="Single"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding Selected}" HeightRequest="20">

            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
         </CollectionView>

        <HorizontalStackLayout Margin="0,20,0,0">
            <Label Text="This is the selected item: "/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Selected}"/>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>

    </VerticalStackLayout>
```

Here is what it looks like on an Android emulator:

[image]

Here is is the iPhone emulator:

[image]

On Android, it seems that everything in the VerticalStackLayout is Centered. On iOS that is not the case. Also, note that on iOS, the CollectionView starts on the far left edge of the screen even though the left Margin of the VerticalStackLayout that contains it is set to "10". CollectionView seems to ignore it's parent's properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That may due to you haven't set a **WidthRequest** for CollectionView. Otherwise, it doesn't know the width of the CollectionView. Try to set the WidthRequest:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionViewElements}" 
 WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="20" 
 ...>
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion Liqun. If I set WidthRequest for the CollectionView it is centered! Strangely enough, so is the text below the CollectionView. While this is a viable workaround, it should not be necessary. The same code works as expected on Android and Windows. The underlying system should know how wide the CollectionView is and center it appropriately. Thanks again for the suggestion!

Comment: Unfortunately, the full WidthRequest is centered in the Layout, however, the CollectionView is left-justified within the WidthRequest. I have to mess with the WidthRequest for each CollectionView to get it to properly center. Specifying a WidthRequest is a temporary workaround. I reported this as a bug to MSFT.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Then you may use a Style for CollectionView. You could refer to  [Style apps using XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/styles/xaml?view=net-maui-7.0).

Comment: The problem is that each CollectionView is a different width. I don't think Style can help me in this situation.

Comment: To make CollectionView's items left-align on Windows, I have to set Label.WidthRequest to 2,000. This seems to be a clear bug.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried applying HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" to the labels? I had a similar problem and once I did this it worked without having to set the WidthRequest.

```
 <HorizontalStackLayout Margin="0,20,0,0">
        <Label Text="This is the selected item: " HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Selected}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
 </HorizontalStackLayout>
```